# EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION only in iPhone 5 simulator

Tags: swift, ios-simulator, ios10

Running my code on the iPhone 5 simulator throws the exception shown in the image.
Running the code on any of the other simulators is just fine.

I can't spot where I made a mistake in this unspectacular line of code.
Does anyone else have this problem?

[image: Exception shown in XCode]

Comment: Is the result the same if you use `Date()` instead of `NSDate()`?

Comment: Actually that code is quite spectacular. Why are you referring to NSInteger in Swift? Or, if this is Swift 3, to NSDate?

Comment: Also, saying `user!` means "crash me". Even if you think that isn't where the problem lies, failing to check that `user` is not `nil` is just foolish.

Comment: Also, I sure hope `configureDatabase()` does not depend on anything you do during `signInAnonymously`, because `configureDatabase` is executed _first_, before `self.refUsers` ever gets set.

Comment: @matt I'm new to swift and ios dev. Reading blogs and stackoverflow i came up with this. The function does only set up some listeners for database changes. Firebase handles the initialization inside database(). Thanks for the tip with user. I thik i'll change that in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`NSInteger` (which is a type alias for `Int` in Swift) is a 32-bit
integer on 32-bit platforms like the iPhone 5.
The result of

```
NSInteger(NSDate().timeIntervalSince1970) * 1000
```

is `1480106653342` (at this moment) and does not fit into the
range `-2^31 ... 2^31-1` of 32-bit (signed) integers.
Therefore Swift aborts the execution. (Swift does not "truncate"
the result of integer arithmetic operations as it is done in some
other programming languages, unless you specifically use the 
"overflow" operators like `&*`.)

You can use `Int64` for 64-bit computations on *all* platforms:

```
Int64(NSDate().timeIntervalSince1970 * 1000)
```

In your case, if a string is needed:

```
let lastLogin = String(Int64(NSDate().timeIntervalSince1970 * 1000))
```

Comment: Didn't know about that 32 vs. 64 bit platform thing, but i'll give it a try though

Comment: Thank you for the tip with the platform difference. That one made it clear to me why it doesn't work. Using our given suggestion didn't help me because firebase doesn't like the typ Int64 in the first place. To get the milliseconds since Epoc(1970) i came up with round(NSDate().timeIntervalSince1970 * 1000

Comment: @Dreanaught: You still can convert it to a string, as you did in your original code, see updated answer.

Comment: Actually, no It turned out that the value is saved as string and not as numerical type(with no decimal places) which was what i initially wanted.