# Swift convert Double to Int

Tags: ios, swift, date, date-conversion

I am trying to convert Double to Int in swift. The code compiles well, but throws an exception at Run time. I have checked that the value isnt overflowing the range of int.

I need that to convert double to int for my timestamp conversions.

```
extension Date {
var millisecondsSince1970:Int {
return Int((self.timeIntervalSince1970 * 1000.0).rounded())
   }
}
```

Comment: You say it “throws an exception at Run time”. Edit your question to include as many details about the exception as possible: what is printed in the debug console, Xcode's description of the exception, the stack trace, and anything else that might be relevant.

Comment: Where did you test this? A device or the Simulator? Which one? Note that Ints are smaller on 32-bit devices, compare https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40811559/exc-bad-instruction-only-in-iphone-5-simulator

Comment: I tested this on a device.

Comment: Which device? iPhone, iPad? Which model?

Comment: @MartinR I tested this on iPhone 6. The link you sent worked for it. It was due to overflowing of timestamp value from the range of Int. Since this is a run time error thats why the code was compiling but throwing exception on execution.